# PROCV - Como evitar a janela para selecionar planilha externa quando inexistente

Tags: microsoft-excel, exceção

Tenho uma `planilha` que usa acesso a dados de `lookup` de outras `planilhas` `PROCV`, mas são fórmulas flutuantes, ou seja, elas se alteram de acordo com a entrada em campos especificos.

Essa alteração ocorre através de `Macro`, que simplesmente altera o `planilha` alvo do `PROCV`. Substituindo o trecho do caminho e nome da `planilha` pelo equivalente de outra `planilha` alvo.

Por exemplo ficheiro:

```
Planilha_Geral.xlsx
```

Pasta:

`C:\Users\usuario\Desktop`

Tem em uma das suas células a seguinte fórmula:

```
=procv(H1;'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Empresa_A_Outubro.xlsx'!$H$1:$L$300;6;falso)
```

Terei outras células onde buscará `planilhas` referentes à outros meses e em determinada ocasião, uma macro roda reconhecendo e copiando o trecho inicial da fórmula:

```
=procv(H1;'C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\Empresa_A_
```

Substitui o trecho de endereçamento de `planilha` por outro trecho, por exemplo:

```
Planilha B.xlsx
```

E finalmente copiando o final da fórmula que já estava na célula, por exemplo:

```
Dezembro.xlsx'!$H$1:$L$300;6;falso)
```

Isso porque a intenção é apenas mudar o foco entre empresas e concentrar dados de interessantes para todos os meses (que estão em planilhas separadas).

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém existe a possibilidade de a planilha que o procv venha a pontar não existir, o que eu imaginei que, em caso de planilha inexistente, o procv retornaria erro. Tratei isso adicionando no inicio da equação o seguinte:

```
=SEERRO(
```

E no final:

```
, "Não tem.")
```

Porém, o procv ao não encontrar uma planilha apontada, antes mesmo de considerar o tratamento de erro abre uma janela solicitando que seja apontada corretamente a planilha, sendo necessário apertar ESC PARA CADA CÉLULA para que se aplique o tratamento SEERRO().

Considerando que cada planilha é referente a um mês e cada mês trará 40 informações de 4 setores, temos:

```
40 * 4 = 160
```

Ou seja, cada vez que a macro rodar e substituir a fórmula do PROCV, para cada mês que não houver planilha da Empresa selecionada será necessário apertar ESC 160 vezes para que seja finalizada a macro.

Alguma ideia de como posso evitar a abertura dessa janela de seleção de planilha?

Comment: Você pode tentar verificar se o arquivo existe antes, com `If Len(Dir(DIRETORIO_DO_ARQUIVO+EXTENSÃO)) = 0` - Nesse caso, se for igual a zero, não existe. E ai apontar o procv para o próprio arquivo em uma celula morta; Eu tentei dar valor falso no `Application.DisplayAlerts`,`Application.EnableEvents` e `Application.ScreenUpdating`, mas nada funcionou... A solução precisa ser código mesmo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insira a linha abaixo no início do código:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

E antes do `End Sub`, insira:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```